# Set TypoScript from Extbase Controller?

Tags: php, typo3, typoscript, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

How can I set TS settings directly from my Extbase (6.2)'s controller?

So here:

```
/**
 * action show
 *
 * @param \STUBR\Apievents\Domain\Model\Event $event
 * @return void
 */
public function showAction(\STUBR\Apievents\Domain\Model\Event $event) {

    // Set plugin.tx_apievents_displayevents.settings.something to value x
    // --> how?

    // go on

    $this->view->assign('event', $event);
}
```

So I could do in setup.txt

```
lib.something < plugin.tx_apievents_displayevents.settings.something
```

But how?

Comment: And, also: is there a way to set ANY TypoScript from PHP directly? Not just my extension's settings?

Comment: if you set plugin.tx_apievents_displayevents.settings.something = value and then you'll get in your action using $this->settings['something'] and you can overwrite value as well $this->settings['something'] = x and in view $this->view->assign('settings', $this->settings); Is that you mean or something I get wrong

Comment: I wanted to access that setting from the TS context, from outside the extension

Comment: you can find all TS configuration of whole site in $GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl->setup

Comment: Can I also write into `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->tmpl->setup`?

Comment: TS is configuration lang and converted into PHP multidimensional array so this is the array I guess. where you get the whole config. I did not try but we can push our value into this global array, I used it into one of my extension for news TS config

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially what a userFunc does. See https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/UserAndUserInt/Index.html
However TS is usually used for configuration that is being used by code. Not the other way around. If you're looking for a way to store temporary values you could also look at the cache manager.
What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I was trying to pass a setting to `plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.prefill` from an extbase/fluid template without relying on a get parameter.

Comment: If you are concerned with security you might as well use POST to pass the values. You could use the prefill TS setting of powermail to grab the POST values. If I understand correctly, the values will change dynamically? Then it doesn't seem like a good idea to store them anywhere, not even temporarily. For reference: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/powermail/ForAdministrators/GoodToKnow/PrefillField/Index.html

Comment: It's for a list / detail page, see the powermail channel on typo3.slack.org :-) – I'm fine with GET, I just thought there should be a way to communicate between Fluid and TS